# Exception Handling: exception being handled multiple times

Tags: python, mysql, exception, mysql-python

I have a python script which downloads certain data from the internet (from a list of URLS) and stores it in a MySQL database. My code is something along these lines:

```
try:
    con = mdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = 'root', passwd = 'gatech', db ='SpecialProb', charset = 'utf8');
    cur = con.cursor()
    print " Database Connection Parameters set"
except mdb.Error, e:  
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)
try:
    for item in listURLs[index:]:
        try:
            r2 = requests.get(item)
        except:
            print "Could not fetch data"
            print "Exception: ", sys.exc_info()[0]
            continue

         ## Some code to fetch Name, ID from the internet, which I have tested and which works correctly. ##
         try:
             cur.execute("INSERT into TABLENAME (NAME, ID" 
             ") VALUES (%s, %s)",
             (totalName, ID))

             print("Value inserted in database.\n")
             countInsert += 1;
             con.commit() 
         except mdb.IntegrityError:
             print "Most likely cause: Database already contains this entry."
             print "Message from system: "
             print "Error %d: %s\n" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
             continue
except:
    print "'For loop exception: ", sys.exc_info()[0]        
    sys.exit(0)
```

The data which I fetch could be duplicate and I don't want the duplicate data to be inserted into the database and the code should go over the next iteration etch the next data instead of storing the data. So I have the `except mdb.IntegrityError:` line there which takes care of the duplicates.

However, after catching the exception for the duplicate entry the code, instead of going over the next iteration goes to the `except` which I have set for the `for` loop. 
Here's what I get:

```
Most likely cause: Database already contains this entry. 
Message from system:
'For loop exception:  <type 'exceptions.NameError'>
```

Why does this happen? And how do I prevent from happening this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please 1) fix the indentation, 2) Post the actual exception you got?

Comment: Also, don't open the connection for every item and don't create a copy `listURLs[index:]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your e would not be defined causing exception in your except block.
Use `mdb.IntegrityError,e` like you did for `except mdb.Error, e`